# Can I use Spring(MVC) with nginx instead of tomcat?

Tags: spring-mvc, nginx, tomcat, load-balancing, autoscaling

Let me explain what I want to achieve. There will be an ec2 instance which will have my spring code running, in that if the number of web requests are too high then I want to spawn another instance to handle that extra requests. How can I achieve it and how does nginx fit into this?

Comment: No you cannot, you need to use a servlet container. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to host my web server on ec2 instance and want to do load balancing. But I dont want to use aws load balancer. I want to do it using nginx. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you considered having both Nginx and tomcat? It's an older pattern that I have seen in the past.

Comment: so when you say tomcat+nginx. you mean nginx on a  seprate ec2 instance and tomcat+my_spring_code in another ec2 instance?

Comment: You can have both on the same if you want to help manage costs.

Comment: if both are on same then how will nginx do scaling?

Comment: Do you mean load balancing? It should be a matter of just configuration to the ip and ports of the tomcat instances. It could route to the local instance or the one on the other server.

Comment: I guess im getting it wrong. Let me explain what I want to achieve. There will be an ec2 instance which will have my spring code running, in that if the number of web requests are too high then I want to spawn another instance to handle that extra requests. How can I achieve it and how does nginx fit into this?

Comment: Ok, I understand unfortunately however I am not too familiar with AWS to provide an answer. Most of my workloads run on k8s

Comment: @ssc327 oh so if I have to do same thing with kubernetes, then how can I achieve it? do I need nginx, if yes then how will it fit into it?

Comment: In k8s I would setup an auto scaler. Out of the box I could scale in CPU and memory, I think that in your case you want to scale in requests so I would probably use something like KEDA. Of course setting up k8s and KEDA is non-trivial and if AWS offers you an autoscalar that might be your best bet.

Comment: ohh ok, and @ssc327 what if i want to do horizontal scaling?

Comment: What I mentioned previously was for horizontal scaling. If I want vertical scaling that is also simple with resource requests and limits.

Comment: ohh got it....thanx @ssc327